# Remove an Image in QLabel After Button Clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I have qlabels that displaying images . I want to delete image if user clicks remove button . I can learn which image clicked

```
labels[i].mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.remove_image, source_label = labels[i] ,source_image = pixmap)
```

but i couldn't use it and connects with button . How can i remove image ?

Comment: Are these `QLabels` in a `listWidget`?

Comment: @IronFist No , QLabels in Frame . Does it matter ?

Comment: Okey...I was just thinking if these `QLabel`s where in a `listWidget` it would be easy to delete them by *selecting* the ones and deleting them at once. But in your case, you want to delete the image *clicked* by user, is it going to be deleting one image per click or multiple images at one click?

Comment: Deleting One image per click . Above code examples i can get which QLabel clicked but i can't make connect with button click .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `labels[]` has a list of `label`s ID, I think you can do something like:

```
labels[i].mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.remove_image, source_label = labels[i]) #just pass to self.remove_image the label id
```

Then in `self.remove_image` and since `label.clear()` (to clear content of label) is a *SLOT* then, you can connect it to `clicked` signal directly:

```
def remove_image(self, label_id):
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.deleteButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), label_id.clear)
```